# What is the status of polygamy in contemporary Hinduism?

Tags: vedas, marriage, vedanta, sex

What is modern Hinduism's perspectives on polygamy (by modern, say within the last 35 years)?

Is the practice of polygamy consistent with any principles in the Vedas?

Comment: I have never heard of polygamy in either a modern or an ancient setting or being mentioned in the vedas. There is a reference to polyandry with the Pandava brothers in the Bhagavatam, but it was not widely practiced or condoned.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Pandava brothers only? What about consorts of lord krishna? Or lord karthikeya  from the South? Wives of king dasaratha father of lord rama? And surely u will find tales of kings in modern history within india with multiple wives

Comment: There is no place for polygamy in the modern setting. The law forbids it. Even if you have extra-marital affairs, there can only be one dharma patni.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Laws differ from country to country.There are countries that support polygamy.I am looking for answers within hinduism..that enables one to embrace it or give proof to refrain from it..what does lokayata mention  with regard to this or any other nastik philosophy within hinduism

Comment: @user105941 My answer was within Hinduism as well. You asked about modern setting.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Why do you say within the Bhagavatam only?  The Pandavas marrying Draupadi is mentioned in the Mahabharata itself.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking Mahabarata and typed Bhagavatam. Although there are stories of kings having multiple wives, I am not aware of any scriptural reference to support polygamy in general.

Comment: i don't think there is any type or restriction with marrying, actually there is considerations to try to be a one woman man, or a one man woman, but nothing related to any strictness towards no polygamy or no polyandry. Hinduism is a open minded religion, it do talks about wrong and right but never presses you towards your deeds.

Comment: Leaving this open since it states "in modern times". As far as Bhagavatam and Mahabharata, there is plenty of examples there.

Answer (score 1):

Namaste

There is no direct or indirect reference of any sort on polygamy in Hindu scriptures (Manu smriti).  Vedas primarily deal with God & Ultimate Truth.
Marriage & society practises are defined by & in Manu Smriti, which forms basis of a society & its laws consistent with other hindu scriptures.

A king is "permitted" three wifes - first for interests of his kingdom, second for his parents, third of his choice.

Lord Krishna's marriage to devi rukmini is of his own choice, while with Satyabhama was that for kingdom and with Jambava was as a token of his long standing disciple Jambavanth from Ramayana era.

Hinduism focusses on attaining the ultimate truth, which is also termed as moksha.  Rest all are all rules, practises, leading to that path in which practises in a social society are again based on certain rules & laws of mother nature

Hindusim is replete with single minded devotion - "Sati" (Chastity) and to even think of polygamy in the context of hinduism is sheer ignorance and is a "paap".

Comment: @Ananymous Can you please put the references. Btw, as you said a king is permitted 3 wives and given example of Lord Krishna. Well, Lord Krishna did not had only 3 wives, he had 8 main wives, called the Ashta-Bharya. See my question [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7842/1018). So clearly rule of 3 wives should not be applicable.

Comment: *Manusmriti* was written as an idealized legal template, scholars agree that it was never in effect as an actual legal system anywhere in premodern India (eg see Buxbaum D., Davis Jr., D., Menski W.), though it was influential in jurisprudence (theory). So it can't be used as evidence of actual Hindu behavior, polyamorous or not. A better source is P.V. Kane's *History of Dharmasastra*, which extensively documents actual legal and social customs throughout Indian history. Kane does mention polygamy, but it was not a common practice historically, & has almost vanished over the last 100 years

Answer (score 1):

There is discussion of polygamy by Bhishma in Mahabharata Anusasana Parva Section XLVII. Bhishma recommends polygamy for Hindus. That does not mean that Hindus must accept polygamy. Mahabharata itself does not encourage following obsolete practices:

> One should practice what one considers to be one’s duty, guided by 
>   reasons, instead of blindly following the practices of the world.

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXII

Polygamy has been banned for 60 years.